# Replace a space with a zero with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

My layer contains an attribute with a size of 11 characters (of type text) whose variable values are of this type: '12345AB1234'.

Some variable values include a space at the 6th position, like this: '54231 C4356' I'm looking to replace those spaces with a zero ('0').

The following command is used to list the 6th characters of the variable values:

```
select park_index, substring(compar from 6 for 1)
from my table;
```

From there, I tried (without success) the following 2 commands:

```
UPDATE my table
SET compar = REPLACE (compar, substring(compar from 6 for 1),'0')
WHERE substring(compar from 6 for 1) = '';

    
UPDATE my table
SET compar = TRANSLATE (compar, substring(compar from 6 for 1),'0') 
WHERE substring(compar from 6 for 1) = '\U+20';
```

Comment: why not simply use `replace(compar, ' ', '0')` - could there be other spaces in the value that should not be replaced?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Thank you, but it doesn't work (the update request doesn't return an error, but no changes are made)

Comment: Then your WHERE clause seems to not find anything. Did you try `= ' '` instead? (Note `' '`  not `''`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name as much for me, it works, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for both searching and updating. Here is the expression which replaces all (one or more) 'space' ( ) characters with a (only one) zero (`0`).

```
regexp_replace('12345 AB1234', '([ ])+', '0')
```

The update expression can be like this;

```
update my_table set 
    compar = regexp_replace(compar, '([ ])+', '0')
  where
    compar ~ '([ ])+';
```

Here is a sample [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LefRef9_)

Comment: Wow ! Thank You !

Comment: @fcka please accept the answer if its ok.